# Does paypal generate any event after clicking pay now button?

Tags: php, events, paypal, shopping-cart

I've a shopping cart implemented in PHP and the checkout process is handled by PayPal. When the customer presses pay now button in PayPal, does it generate any events so that i may process that information and based on the stock levels in my database decide whether to accept the payment or not?

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423809/php-paypal-a-way-to-validate-a-payment-before-accepting-the-payments) will this help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can do that after payment with [PayPal IPN](https://www.paypal.com/ipn), it sends all the data about purchase back ..

Comment: I've considered using IPN, but i dont' think that solves the following scenario: Suppose the stock level of one of my items A is 1 and two customers CA and CB adds same item to their cart simultaneously and press checkout button in my website. This takes both of them to PayPal website for payment. If MA completes his payment first, he is directed to a NOTIFY_URL in my website and my stock level for the item is adjusted to 0. Now, when MB completes his payment I'm in trouble. Do you have any ideas what I should do here?

Comment: Not really a paypal thing, but you could reduce the stock level /mark an item as taken  atomically when they begin the checkout process, and if the checkout process isn't completed in say 10 minutes return it to stock. This is how ticket booking sites work, for example.

Comment: As soon as the first client adds a item in his basket you save that in a temporary table and when you check for stock, also consider that temp table. If the client does not make payment in 30 minutes or so you can clear his basket and remove that item from temporary table.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Jords and Mihai.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to query your server about stock levels on-click, and submit the form if everything looks OK.

Comment: I could have used PHP to check the stock levels before submitting my form to PayPal, but that does not solve the edge case I mentioned in the comment to the reply given by @Mihai Iorga.